# Argument must be a string or a number, not 'ExponentialDecay'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, learning-rate

I am on Tensorflow 2.4.0, and tried to perform Exponential decay on the learning rate as follows:

```
learning_rate_scheduler = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.1, decay_steps=1000, decay_rate=0.97, staircase=False)
```

and start the learning rate of my optimizer with such decay method:

```
optimizer_to_use = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate_scheduler)
```

the model is compiled as follows

```
model.compile(loss=metrics.contrastive_loss, optimizer=optimizer_to_use, metrics=[accuracy])
```

The train goes well until the third epoch, where the following error is showed:

```
File "train_contrastive_siamese_network_inception.py", line 163, in run_experiment
    history = model.fit([pairTrain[:, 0], pairTrain[:, 1]], labelTrain[:], validation_data=([pairTest[:, 0], pairTest[:, 1]], labelTest[:]), batch_size=config.BATCH_SIZE, epochs=config.EPOCHS, callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1145, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 432, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, numpy_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 2542, in on_epoch_end
    old_lr = float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ExponentialDecay'
```

I checked this issue was even raised in the official keras [Forum](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14331), but no success even there. Plus, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule#used-in-the-notebooks) clearly states that:

> A `LearningRateSchedule` instance can be passed in as the `learning_rate` argument of any optimizer.

What could be the issue?

Comment: It could be a bug in tf

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. I tried with different versions of tensorflow (2.4.0 and 2.8.2) on google colab. Note that the contrastive loss on tensorflow 2.8 can be found in tensorflow_addons.losses. Which definition of the contrastive loss did you use on tf 2.4?

Comment: Any updates or solution on this? I just had the same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed in `model.compile()` are not in the exact way. You have defined **metrics** in loss parameter `loss=metrics.contrastive_loss` which should be [tfa.losses.ContrastiveLoss()](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/ContrastiveLoss)

If you are using `TensorFlow 2.4`, you need to install a specific version of tensorflow_addons (between `0.10 - 0.14`) to access and use tensorflow addons APIs - **ContrastiveLoss**

**The fixed code is:**

```
model.compile(loss = tfa.losses.ContrastiveLoss(), 
              optimizer = optimizer_to_use, 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

(Attaching the replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/d784362a84bbb68d73a0f85da61cd3e6/73897736.ipynb) here for your reference.)